# Linking facebook iframe share with google analytics

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, google-analytics

I have successfully linked my analytics to track facebook events.

The tracking of likes and unlikes works without any problems. The problem appears with the share button, due to the fact it's a iframe. After clicking share you get a popup/iframe where you can share. Any ideas on how to change this code to track the share events? Or maybe the code needs to be inline in the FB div? That way every on click will push a ga? That will count just the clicks on the share button even if someone doesn't share something...

Any ideas? Anyone managed to achieve this in some way?

The none working fragment: // i left it as message send, doesn't make a difference for me, so this is intentional.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('message.send', function(targetUrl) {
_gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'send', targetUrl]);});
```

All of the code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
var like = function (url, html_element) {
    console.log("like");
};
var unlike = function (url, html_element) {
    console.log("unlike");
};
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', like);
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', unlike);
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',function(targetURL) {
        ga('send', 'social', 'Facebook', 'like', targetURL);});
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',function(URL) {
        ga('send', 'social', 'Facebook', 'unlike', URL);});
FB.Event.subscribe('message.send', function(targetUrl) {
    _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'send', targetUrl]);});
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create',function(href) {
        ga('send', 'social', 'Facebook', 'comment added', href);});
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove',function(loc) {
        ga('send', 'social', 'Facebook', 'comment deleted', loc);});
```

};

Thank you.

Comment: `message.send` should work for tracking message sends through the Send button, according to the documentation. But for tracking shares, there is no such event. If you want to track shares, you could use the Share dialog instead – but that will only give you a return value, if the user is logged in to your app and has granted `publish_actions` permission beforehand, so that’d be a lot more intrusive.

Comment: True, that's why I couldn't find anything about tracking shares. Thank you for the input.

Are you also able to help with fb:login and the permissions needed to set a like, adter fb:login so it is granted the default user privacy, not always private?